# MS Access Parameter Query Results in Error

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a query that used a field from a form as a parameter in a crosstab query and it worked fine, the contents of the field are like 2017-18 etc. But now I have 2 forms that run the same query and have used TempVars, I have dim/defined the TempVars in the VBA before the query launches and have used the following as a parameter in the query;

```
[Tempvars]![varFinDate]
```

But when the query runs I get the error message;

> The expression is typed incorrectly, or is too complex to be
>   evaluated. For example, a numeric express may contain too many
>   complicated elements. Try simplifying the expression by assigns parts
>   of the express to variables.

I have used the same principle on many queries without issue.

Comment: Have you declared the parameters in the crosstab query? - A crosstab has to have the parameters predefined.

Comment: Please share all the relevant code (SQL, setting tempvars, when what happens). Currently, your question contains very little information for us to debug it.

Comment: @Minty OK that did it, please add as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A crosstab has to have the parameters predefined. Have you declared the parameters in the crosstab query?

If not you can set them in the Query editor by right click and select Parameters property in the designer.

Comment: Not an answer, rather a suggestion.

Comment: It was the answer - see the comments against the original post.